# My d3.scaleLinear function won't scale past 9

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

For a school project, I have to create a graph using a JSON file with input data. Using d3.scaleLinear() and using my x and y values as input, I am trying to get my graph to scale so all of my points will be graphed. Without using a JSON file and using a simple var data = [[20,  5]] and scaling by using d[0] and d[1] where d.x and d.y are works. But I can't figure out how to get it to work by using a JSON file as the input data.

```
<script>
        // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
            width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        
        // append the svg object to the body of the page
        var svg = d3.select("#scatter-chart")
          .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        
        //Read the data
        d3.json("test_points.json", function(data) {
        
          // Add X axis
          var x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                        return d.x;
                    })])
            .range([0, width])
          svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
        
          // Add Y axis
          var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                        return d.y;
                    })])
            .range([height, 0]);
          svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
        
          // Add dots
          svg.append('g')
            .selectAll("dot")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
              .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.x); } )
              .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.y); } )
              .attr("r", 6)
              .style("fill", "#ff0084")
        
        })
        </script>
```

using test_points.json in a sperate file

```
[
    {"x":"11","y":"14"},
    {"x":"5","y":"17"},
    {"x":"7","y":"19"},
    {"x":"1","y":"7"},
    {"x":"27","y":"3"},
    {"x":"5","y":"0"},
    {"x":"9","y":"4"},
    {"x":"13","y":"1"},
    {"x":"17","y":"20"},
    {"x":"19","y":"16"},
    {"x":"12","y":"1"},
    {"x":"11","y":"9"},
    {"x":"1","y":"7"},
    {"x":"0","y":"4"}
]
```

Comment: Your title says you have an issue with the scale, but your question appears to be "I can't figure out how to get it to work by using a JSON file as the input data". Is it possible to clarify further? If the question is the latter *and* you are using d3v5, you'll need to use the format `d3.json("file").then(function(data) { ...`, but I'm not sure if this addresses your question.

Comment: I changed the title to clarify, I could try that when I’m at my computer but I believe it’s d3v4. Are d.x and d.y the correct commands for those spots?

Answer (score 1):

Your first title actually contains the hint to fix your code (I rolled back your edit).

When you say *"my d3.scaleLinear function won't scale past 9"* it becomes clear that you're using the JSON values as **strings**, not as numbers (unlike your hardcoded `var data`, which contain numbers). The thing is that strings behave differently than numbers:

```js
console.log("9" > "8000000")
```

As you can see, when comparing strings nine seems to be bigger than eight million... what's actually happening here is that strings are compared letter by letter, and so `"9"` is bigger than `"8"`.

The solution is just converting the strings to numbers:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.x = +d.x;
  d.y = +d.y;
});
```

Here is your original code:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{
    "x": "11",
    "y": "14"
  },
  {
    "x": "5",
    "y": "17"
  },
  {
    "x": "7",
    "y": "19"
  },
  {
    "x": "1",
    "y": "7"
  },
  {
    "x": "27",
    "y": "3"
  },
  {
    "x": "5",
    "y": "0"
  },
  {
    "x": "9",
    "y": "4"
  },
  {
    "x": "13",
    "y": "1"
  },
  {
    "x": "17",
    "y": "20"
  },
  {
    "x": "19",
    "y": "16"
  },
  {
    "x": "12",
    "y": "1"
  },
  {
    "x": "11",
    "y": "9"
  },
  {
    "x": "1",
    "y": "7"
  },
  {
    "x": "0",
    "y": "4"
  }
];

// Add X axis
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })])
  .range([0, width])
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// Add Y axis
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// Add dots
svg.append('g')
  .selectAll("dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d.y);
  })
  .attr("r", 6)
  .style("fill", "#ff0084")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

And here is the same code using numbers instead of strings:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{
    "x": "11",
    "y": "14"
  },
  {
    "x": "5",
    "y": "17"
  },
  {
    "x": "7",
    "y": "19"
  },
  {
    "x": "1",
    "y": "7"
  },
  {
    "x": "27",
    "y": "3"
  },
  {
    "x": "5",
    "y": "0"
  },
  {
    "x": "9",
    "y": "4"
  },
  {
    "x": "13",
    "y": "1"
  },
  {
    "x": "17",
    "y": "20"
  },
  {
    "x": "19",
    "y": "16"
  },
  {
    "x": "12",
    "y": "1"
  },
  {
    "x": "11",
    "y": "9"
  },
  {
    "x": "1",
    "y": "7"
  },
  {
    "x": "0",
    "y": "4"
  }
];

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.x = +d.x;
  d.y = +d.y;
});

// Add X axis
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })])
  .range([0, width])
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// Add Y axis
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// Add dots
svg.append('g')
  .selectAll("dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d.y);
  })
  .attr("r", 6)
  .style("fill", "#ff0084")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```